# How do I configure LDAP plugin for SonarQube Server?

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

I am trying to set the correct values for LDAP properties of a SonarQube Server. I am having difficulty finding a resource that explains the list of possible values for these properties, and understand which one to use in which scenario? 
I am referring to https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin
For example,

```
Property1: ldap.user.request    
Default_Value: (&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={login}))
Example for AD: (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
```

Here what are all the possible values for `objectClass`?
When do i use value `inetOrgPerson`?
When do I use value `user`?
When do I use `uid`?
When do I use `sAMAccountName`? What does it mean?

There are several other properties like `memberAttribute` , `idAttribute` which I dont understand.

Is there a guide available which describes ALL ldap properties and ALL their possible values? I tried searching on LDAP.com, openldap.org but couldnt find relevant answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i use as my LDAP configuration in the conf file.
Hope that helps you make a good start.

```
# LDAP configuration
# General Configuration
sonar.security.realm: LDAP
sonar.security.savePassword: true
sonar.authenticator.createUsers: true
sonar.security.localUsers: admin,sonar-build
ldap.url: ldap://ipadress:389
ldap.bindDn: CN=SonarUser,OU=Service Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com  
ldap.bindPassword: {aes}xxx

# User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn: DC=domain,DC=com  
ldap.user.request: (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login})) 
ldap.user.realNameAttribute: cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute: mail

# Group Configuration
ldap.group.baseDn: DC=domain,DC=com  
ldap.group.request: (&(objectClass=group)(memberUid={uid}))
```

Comment: this is again an example of an LDAP confguration, I am looking for resources/explanation of what these properties and values mean.

Comment: You can find explanation of each properties on: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/delegated-auth/